# What does "independent" bind to in this sentence?

Tags: adjectives, adverbs, commas

Which of the following two sentences is correct?

- A is valid independent of B.
- A is valid independently of B.

In other words, does independent bind to "are" or "valid"?  I tend towards the first version.  I also thought that there could be a comma after valid, turning the second half of the sentence more into an explanatory phrase.

Comment: I'd say "independent of" when the object complement of "of" is nominal (i.e. noun-like), but "independently of" when the complement of "of" is a clause, e.g. a whether-clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking up "true independent of" and "true independently of" in Google searches shows that though both occur, the former usage predominates. There is a similar picture with "valid independent/ly of", though these are not as common.

The phrase following true/valid is certainly modifying [the statement in] the independent clause, *A is true*. This means that 'independent/ly of B' is a (sentence) adverbial. This means that 'independent/ly' must be an adverb (or 'sentence-modifier') rather than an adjective.

The fact that more people seem to choose to use 'independent' as a flat adverb here than the -ly-form does not appear to have been picked up on by many dictionaries.

Looking at a parallel case, we can find that RHK Webster's labels 'regardless of' an idiom, a compound preposition, although 'regardless' is classed as a (flat) adverb (when not modifying a noun) in most dictionaries; [Collins Thesaurus of the English Language](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/regardless) has

> **regardless** adverb ...
>
> 2. (with **of**) irrespective of, without reference to, without regard to, despite, discounting, disregarding, notwithstanding, unconcerned
>      about, heedless of, unmindful of